# How to generate the missing dates in a schedule?

Tags: c#

I have a schedule that only contains one week of training (31 workouts), and now I need to generate the rest of the workouts until the end of the schedule (eg. 20120601-20120831).
So I thought of maybe loop the workouts and put addDays(7) on all workout.date.

I have tried using foreach and a for, but cant get it to work.

my GenerateSchedule method:

```
public ActionResult GenerateSchedule(int scheduleId)
    {
        //get schedule included list of 31 workouts
        //only added one week on workouts
        var schedule = _scheduleServices.GetSchedule(scheduleId);
        var workouts = schedule.Workouts.ToList();
        int i = 0;
        for(var day = schedule.FromDate; day.Date <= schedule.ToDate; day =  day.AddDays(1))
        {
            foreach (var workout in workouts)
            {

            }

            var newWorkout = new WorkoutFormModel
            {
                ScheduleId = workouts[i].ScheduleId,
                Date = workouts[i].Date.AddDays(7),
                StartTime = workouts[i].StartTime,
                EndTime = workouts[i].EndTime,
                InstructorId = workouts[i].Instructor.Id,
                CourseId = workouts[i].Course.Id,
            };

            i++;
            _workoutServices.AddWorkout(newWorkout);
        }

        /*
        foreach(var workout in schedule.Workouts)
        {
            if (workout.Date.AddDays(7) <= schedule.ToDate)
            {
                var newWorkout = new WorkoutFormModel
                                     {
                                         ScheduleId = workout.ScheduleId,
                                         Date = workout.Date.AddDays(7),
                                         StartTime = workout.StartTime,
                                         EndTime = workout.EndTime,
                                         InstructorId = workout.Instructor.Id,
                                         CourseId = workout.Course.Id,

                                     };
                _workoutServices.AddWorkout(newWorkout);
            }
        }*/

        return RedirectToAction("Overview", new { scheduleId });
    }
```

updated:

```
    private static List<WorkoutFormModel> ExtendSchedule(Schedule schedule)
    {
        var workoutList = new List<WorkoutFormModel>();

        for (var workoutStart = schedule.FromDate; workoutStart <= schedule.ToDate; workoutStart = workoutStart.AddDays(7))
        {


            workoutList.AddRange(schedule.Workouts.Select(Workout => new WorkoutFormModel
            {
                ScheduleId = schedule.Id,
                Date = workoutStart.Add(Workout.WeekOffset),
                StartTime = Workout.StartTime,
                EndTime = Workout.EndTime,

                Course = Workout.Course
            }));
        }

        return workoutList;
    }
```

Comment: Are you just keeping your workouts in a List? (Basically in a linear array?) Could you instead store them in a HashMap? Then you could use a custom subclass of DateTime as key, and look up workouts from weekday and start time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DateTime` is [immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). That is, `AddDays()` returns a new instance of `DateTime`, leaving the instance you called it on untouched. So your loop might look like this:

```
for(var day = schedule.FromDate; day.Date <= schedule.ToDate; day = day.AddDays(1))
```

**EDIT**: Now that we agree that it is more like a design issue, I suggest this:

- Write the following helper function, as explicit about its inputs as possible:

  ```
  private List<WorkoutFormModel> ExtendSchedule(Schedule schedule, IEnumerable<WorkoutInfo> oneWeekWorkouts)
  {
      var workoutList = new List<WorkoutFormModel>();
      foreach (var workoutStart = schedule.FromDate; workoutStart <= schedule.ToDate; workoutStart = workoutStart.AddDays(7))
      {
          workoutList.AddRange(oneWeekWorkouts.Select(workout => new WorkoutFormModel
                               {
                                   ScheduleId = schedule.Id,
                                   Date = workoutStart.Add(workout.WeekOffset),
                                   StartTime = ?,
                                   EndTime = ?,
                                   InstructorId = workout.Instructor.Id,
                                   CourseId = workout.Course.Id
                               }));
      }

      return workoutList;
  }
  ```

  where `WorkoutInfo` is a class representing the workouts. I named it differently so that it does not collide with the types you have used, but is basically the same thing as the items of your `Schedule.Workouts` list. The main difference is that in my `WorkoutInfo`, you don't keep the particular point of time the workout is going to take place, but rather **an offset** from the beginning of the week, in a form of a `TimeSpan` member `WeekOffset`. With this representation, it's much more straightforward to extend a week's plan to the whole schedule, as you can see.

It's up to you to fill the blanks and align my proposal with your codebase. Maybe you will want to create this new `WorkoutInfo` class, maybe it will be better to merge it somehow with your existing `Workout` class, it depends on the whole picture of your project.

If you encounter any more difficulties, let me know.

Comment: So if I get it right, in your schedule you have one week's workouts defined and you want to extend this pattern to the whole schedule. If this is correct, I think you're not modeling this scenario very well. The function does not give a clear impression of what it is supposed to achieve.

Comment: yes that is correct. I am sorry for the modeling, but don't have a clue what i am doing kind of.

Comment: something is wrong, I get duplicates and missing dates between aug 27 to aug 31 maybe because its not 7 days apart.

Comment: have you given up on this one? Problem now is when i try with only one day (8 workouts) it works fine, but when I add two days = 11 workouts it doesn't work, then it puts the startdate (120604) on all 11 workouts. When it should only add addays(7) to 8 workouts (monday) and then change date to tuesday and addays(7) to three and so on

Comment: i am using your solution. Updated

Comment: That's not how I suggested it. My `ExtendSchedule()` method took explicitely the list of workouts, while yours does not. Not that I want to force you to use my solution, but at least please provide the exact data you are pushing to the method and what outcome do you expect.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14954/discussion-between-n3tx-and-twoflower)